# What is the correct to write a wrapper function to execute a HTTP Get request using curl?

Tags: c, curl

I am trying to write a wrapper function to make a http get request using lib curl. However I am unable to figure out how to return the headers and the response body using `curl_easy_setopt` functions with callback functions.

Here is my code of my wrapper function.

```c
typedef struct {
  char* key;
  char* value;
} http_header_t;

typedef struct {
  int status;
  char *body;
  http_header_t headers[MAX_HEADERS];
} http_response_t;

size_t http_response_write(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userdata) {

  return size * nmemb;
}

size_t header_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata) {
  http_response_t *response = (http_response_t*)userdata;

  printf("buf: %s\n", buffer);
  return nitems * size;
}

/**
 * @brief HTTP GET request
 * 
 * @param response The response buffer
 * @param url The URL to request
 */
void http_get(http_response_t *response, const char *url) {
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, header_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, http_response_write);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
}
```

I do not understand what the userstata parameter at the callback function `CUROPT_WRITEHEADER` mean and others parameters. Do you need to pass out the your struct like this?

```
size_t header_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata) {
  http_response_t *response = (http_response_t) userdata;
  response->headers = buffer; // lets pretend that the headers key type in my struct is a char
  return (int) response; // return the pointer address of the response
}
```

I expect to be able to write out the content of my struct so it fill out all of it's fields.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand what the userstata parameter at the callback function CUROPT_WRITEHEADER mean and others parameters.

`CUROPT_WRITEHEADER` does not set a callback function; [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html) does that, for a function to receive header data (you can instead set [`CURLOPT_HEADER`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADER.html), which causes the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback to receive all data, headers and body, but that's messier).

`CUROPT_WRITEHEADER` is basically an alias for [`CURLOPT_HEADERDATA`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERDATA.html); both set data to pass as the `userdata` parameter of `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` (curl doesn't set this itself; it will pass NULL if you don't set it). It's analogous to [`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) for [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html). Use it as `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` is used in the sample code:

```
void http_get(http_response_t *response, const char *url) {
    //...
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, http_response_write);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, response);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, response);
```

Each header is passed separately to the header callback function, so you'll want to keep track of the number of headers somewhere (`http_response_t` being the natural place).

```
typedef struct {
    //...
    size_t nHeaders;
} http_response_t;
```

As for processing the headers, you have it right in `header_callback` where you cast `userdata` to a `http_response_t`. The assignment of `buffer` to the `response->headers` isn't quite right, but I'm assuming you put that in as a placeholder based on the "lets pretend" comment. The return value of both callbacks must be the number of bytes processed.

Since `buffer` is owned & managed by curl, when the callback function parses `buffer` it will need to create the header fields and copy the header data. This may be passed off to some other functions you create for the purpose (e.g. `http_header_set_key` and `http_header_set_value`) which would take on that [responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Even better, pass the responsibility of parsing the header line to another function (which itself would call functions responsible for creating & setting the fields):

```
// In the "http_response" library
// return non-0 if error
int http_header_set_key(char *buffer, size_t nChars, http_header_t *header);
// return non-0 if error
int http_header_set_value(char *buffer, size_t nChars, http_header_t *header);
// return bytes processed (should be == bufSize)
size_t http_header_parse_line(char *buffer, size_t bufSize, http_header_t *header);

//...

// In the client library

size_t header_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nItems, void *userdata) {
    http_response_t *response = (http_response_t) userdata;
    int iHdr = response->nHeaders;
    if (iHdr >= MAX_HEADERS - 1) {
        // Error: ran out of space in response to store header; signal this
        // condition somehow.
        // ...
        // If signaling doesn't interrupt this function, must stop here
        return 0;
    }
    int nProcessed = http_header_parse_line(buffer, size * nItems, response->headers + iHdr);
    if (nProcessed) {
        // A header was added to response->headers.
        ++response->nHeaders;
    }
    return nProcessed;
}
```

Note that `buffer` is not null-terminated, which is why its size is passed to `http_header_parse_line`. If instead you want `http_header_parse_line` to operate on a C string, you'll need to first copy & null terminate the header line from `buffer`; this may simplify `http_header_parse_line` slightly, but will complicate `header_callback` and be less efficient.

Comment: What option do I need to use so I can set a callback for http_header_init ?

Comment: @ViniDalvino: `http_header_init` was not a callback but a proposed function that you'd write and call from within the callbacks. Hopefully, the update is clearer (and more specific as to design).